# Why doesn't this Excel (Mac 2011) goal seek macro work?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change()
    CheckGoalSeek
End Sub

Private Sub CheckGoalSeek()
    With Worksheets("Inverse")
        .Range("E19").GoalSeek _
        Goal:=0, _
        ChangingCell:=.Range("B19")
    End With
```

This is on a worksheet named "Inverse". Cell E19 contains the difference between my actual goal (an input variable in C19) and the calculated value (in D19), so the goal is for E19 to be zero. B19 is the cell to be varied. The value calculator calls a macro function that works fine. If I manually enter the goal seek parameters from the "Tools" menu, it works fine. But when I edit cell C19 to change the goal, it doesn't get the answer. It seems to be calculating but it doesn't find the goal.

Comment: I know of two possible errors, it may get a *zero divisor* kind of deal and stop working. That's plain bullcrap. The other - more frequent - issue is that the value you're tring to edit is not a value but a formula.

Comment: No, cell C19 just holds a numeric value that I type into the cell. And I don't see any possibility of a divide by zero error (which in any case should be reported by some error message, right?). Grasping at straws here, but should "With Worksheets" possibly be "With Worksheet"?

Comment: You can check that with a *Select* method.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work using AppleScript; Excel/Mac has a "goal seek" verb. Piece of cake.